Facing an issue in CircleCI Pipeline when cloning the nvm repo
I just started to face this issue in the CircleCI pipeline. Here is the script and error detail:
Script:
#!/bin/bash -eo pipefail
wget -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.3/install.sh | bash
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"
nvm install v16
nvm install 16.13.1
nvm alias default 16.13.1
echo 'export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"' >> $BASH_ENV
echo '[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"' >> $BASH_ENV

Error:
=> Downloading nvm from git to '/home/circleci/.nvm'
=> Cloning into '/home/circleci/.nvm'...
ERROR: Permission to nvm-sh/nvm.git denied to deploy key
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
Failed to clone nvm repo. Please report this!

Exited with code exit status 2

CircleCI received exit code 2

I have also added my comment on the issue raised in GitHub repo of NVM but also wanted to ask from Stack Overflow community if someone has faced this issue or have any solution.

The issue is resolved now.
